# UIImage not loading from AWS S3 url

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, uiimage, sdwebimage

I'm trying to download an image from a URL but the image doesn't load.

I ported this class from objective-C to swift and this specific part of the code stopped working. 
My URL looks like this. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

`https://mydomain-files.s3.amazonaws.com/files/log/773/IMG_20200408_125029.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=mycredentials%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200413T171303Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=mysignature`

```
cell.previewImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "nodata"), completed: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in                
      if image != nil {
          cell.previewImageView.image = image
      }
})
```

I have tried using just `https://mydomain-files.s3.amazonaws.com/files/log/773/IMG_20200408_125029.jpg` this part and it doesn't work either. The image loads fine in `Volley for Android` and inside the browser.

## Error

`Error Domain=SDWebImageErrorDomain Code=1001 "Downloaded image has 0 pixels" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Downloaded image has 0 pixels})`

## Edit 2:

I have tried adding `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)` to the url, it just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, since the image does not load it means that `image` is `nil`.

I would advise you to convert your code to the one below and handle errors appropriately:

```
cell.previewImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "nodata"), completed: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
  if let error = error {
      // Handle errors here
      // It may be as simple as forgetting to whitelist S3 url in Info.plist
  }                
  else if image != nil {
      cell.previewImageView.image = image
  }
})
```

If there are no errors, check the contents of other variables – they might give you a clue as to what's going wrong.

Comment: It says the image size is 0 pixels, I have the error handler in my code, I just didn't write it here

Comment: what is the output of print(image)?

Comment: The image is nil

Comment: The imageUrl seems fine btw

Comment: No no, I got this error `Error Domain=SDWebImageErrorDomain Code=1001 "Downloaded image has 0 pixels" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Downloaded image has 0 pixels})`

Comment: what is the url? I would try to issue a get request using URLSession to see what errors it would return

Comment: https://biobot-nucleo-files.s3.amazonaws.com/bitacoras_files/actividades_log/773/880/IMG_20200408_125029.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAUAR635Q23KEUYY3O%2F20200413%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200413T185000Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=07111a5d7b369370c72ca5dae6437416dd45deea223bdb0b832241064c1aa946

Comment: I just found out that, if I sign out and sign in, the images load a couple of times, but if I close the app, the images stop loading.

Comment: How often do you update your link? I think that it may simply expire and that's why you get this error. For example, when I try the link now I get Access Denied. You are using a 3rd party library for these requests – it may be the case that they do not process such errors appropriately :)

Comment: Actually, we noticed that those images that were failing, were using some kind of color filter in sRGB which apple doesn't currently support, so we tried edditing that image and removing the filter, and it works perfectly. In fact, safari can't open that photo. You can try it, You can't see it in mac's/iOS telegram. Because the format is not supported